# How do I generate tables simply and fast in R?

Tags: r

I'm not asking for the str() or glimpse()-commands but for a better way of generating tables.

Let's say I want to see if my background variable (gymnasiegrov) affects my result variable (totstatus_bin).

I then write

```
vettig_tabell<-table(fulldata$gymnasiegrov,fulldata$totstatus_bin)
```

I then have to convert this do a data frame in order to make it easily readable in Rstudio:

```
vettig_tabell<-as.data.frame(vettig_tabell)
```

I then have to spread the values so I can see the different outcomes on the same row for each category:

```
vettig_tabell<-spread(vettig_tabell, Var2, Freq)
```

If I want to calculate relative frequencies I have to calculate them like this:

```
vettig_tabell<-vettig_tabell%>%mutate(ongoing=`pågående studier`/(`pågående studier´ + ´avbrott eller återbud´))
```

This seems like an unnecessary amount of effort for generating a simple table. Is there any way I can do this simpler and faster?

Excerpt of data:

```
structure(list(gymnasiegrov = c("Hotell- och Restaurang", NA, 
"specialutformat program", "komvux", NA, "bygg, el, fordon, hantverk, sjöfart, industriteknik", 
"estetiska programmet", "komvux", "naturvetenskapliga programmet", 
NA, "specialutformat program", "estetiska programmet", "medieprogrammet/medieproduktion", 
"specialutformat program", "specialutformat program", "komvux", 
"estetiska programmet", "samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", "specialutformat program", 
"friskoleprogram", "teknikprogrammet", "specialutformat program", 
"teknikprogrammet", "Handels- och administrationsprogrammet", 
"Hotell- och Restaurang", "samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", 
"samhälls- och ekonomiprogrammet", "specialutformat program", 
"komvux", "specialutformat program", "specialutformat program", 
"bygg, el, fordon, hantverk, sjöfart, industriteknik", "komvux", 
"Handels- och administrationsprogrammet", "teknikprogrammet", 
"teknikprogrammet", "friskoleprogram", "specialutformat program", 
"naturvetenskapliga programmet", "naturvetenskapliga programmet", 
"samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", "samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", 
"Hotell- och Restaurang", "specialutformat program", "samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "bygg, el, fordon, hantverk, sjöfart, industriteknik", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "komvux", "bygg, el, fordon, hantverk, sjöfart, industriteknik", 
"estetiska programmet", "estetiska programmet", "samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "naturvetenskapliga programmet", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "bygg, el, fordon, hantverk, sjöfart, industriteknik", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "bygg, el, fordon, hantverk, sjöfart, industriteknik", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "bygg, el, fordon, hantverk, sjöfart, industriteknik", 
"naturvetenskapliga programmet", "Handels- och administrationsprogrammet", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "bygg, el, fordon, hantverk, sjöfart, industriteknik", 
"bygg, el, fordon, hantverk, sjöfart, industriteknik", "ekonomiprogrammet/ juridik", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ juridik", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "bygg, el, fordon, hantverk, sjöfart, industriteknik", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "Handels- och administrationsprogrammet", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "estetiska programmet", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "teknikprogrammet", "samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", 
"naturvetenskapliga programmet", "naturvetenskapliga programmet", 
"teknikprogrammet", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", 
"samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", "naturvetenskapliga programmet", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ juridik", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ juridik", 
"samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", "samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", 
"samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", "ekonomiprogrammet/ juridik", 
"teknikprogrammet", "teknikprogrammet", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "naturvetenskapliga programmet", 
"naturvetenskapliga programmet", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "naturvetenskapliga programmet", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ juridik", 
"teknikprogrammet", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "naturvetenskapliga programmet", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ juridik", "naturvetenskapliga programmet", 
"teknikprogrammet", "ekonomiprogrammet/ juridik", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", "estetiska programmet", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ juridik", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "teknikprogrammet", 
"naturvetenskapliga programmet", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ juridik", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), totstatus_bin = c("troligt avbrott eller återbud", 
"troligt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", 
"troligt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"troligt avbrott eller återbud", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", 
"troligt avbrott eller återbud", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", 
"troligt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"troligt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"troligt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", 
"troligt avbrott eller återbud", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", 
"troligt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", 
"troligt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", 
"troligt avbrott eller återbud", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"troligt avbrott eller återbud", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", 
"troligt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", 
"troligt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", 
"troligt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", 
"troligt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"troligt avbrott eller återbud", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", 
"troligt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", 
"troligt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"troligt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier")), row.names = c(NA, -162L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you share some (reproducible) data along with expected output?

Comment: This is not a very good question. It is a bit unclear what exactly your understanding of a table is and since you don't share your data it is hard to follow what would qualify.

Comment: Also: If you think the code is too verbose you can always create your own function. Some people even create their personal R packages with code they often use: https://github.com/dgrtwo/drlib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will produce a data frame that looks like the table without converting to long form and back.  No packages are used.

```
as.data.frame.matrix(table(fulldata))
```

Similarly, to get the averages:

```
as.data.frame.matrix(prop.table(table(fulldata), 1))
```

This will get the final data frame shown in the question:

```
tab <- table(fulldata)
transform(as.data.frame.matrix(tab), ongoing = prop.table(tab, 1)[, 1])
```

### Frequency table

For the frequency table these packages can be used as well:

**1) janitor::tabyl**

For the frequency table, the `tabyl` function in the janitor package can produce tables of class `c("tabyl", "data.frame")`

```
library(janitor)
tabyl(fulldata, gymnasiegrov, totstatus_bin)
```

**2) data.table::dcast**

For the frequency table, this produces a data.frame.  The reshape2 package also has a `dcast` which is used with the same arguments.

```
library(data.table)
dcast(fulldata, gymnasiegrov ~ totstatus_bin)
```

Comment: Could you possibly explain what the "1" in "prop.table(tab, 1)" codes for? I understand that it's somehow used to code for the in-group percentages but I try my best to understand the code that I'm working with!

Comment: 1 means divide each cell by row total of the row it belongs to. ( 2 means divide each by the column total)  For example the first row of `table(fulldata)` is 7,3 so the total is 7+3=10 and dividing by that gives 0.7, 0.3.  See `?prop.table`

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following (assuming that I have understood you correctly) using `data.table`:

**Code**

```
require(data.table); dt = setDT(fulldata)

dt[, Pågående := fifelse(totstatus_bin == 'pågående studier', 1, 0)]
freq_table = dt[, .(Frekvens_Pågående = mean(Pågående)), keyby = gymnasiegrov]
```

Alternatively you can bypass the dummy stage, as indicated by @jangorecki:

```
require(data.table); dt = setDT(fulldata)
dt[, .(Frekvens_Pågående = mean(totstatus_bin == 'pågående studier')), keyby = gymnasiegrov]
```

**Result**

```
> freq_table
                                           gymnasiegrov Frekvens_Pågående
 1:                                                <NA>         0.7272727
 2:              Handels- och administrationsprogrammet         0.7500000
 3:                              Hotell- och Restaurang         0.3333333
 4: bygg, el, fordon, hantverk, sjöfart, industriteknik         0.7000000
 5:                          ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi         0.6181818
 6:                          ekonomiprogrammet/ juridik         0.7000000
 7:                                estetiska programmet         0.7142857
 8:                                     friskoleprogram         1.0000000
 9:                                              komvux         0.3333333
10:                     medieprogrammet/medieproduktion         0.0000000
11:                       naturvetenskapliga programmet         0.6428571
12:                     samhälls- och ekonomiprogrammet         1.0000000
13:                    samhällsvetenskapliga programmet         0.6875000
14:                             specialutformat program         0.5454545
15:                                    teknikprogrammet         0.4545455
```

Comment: wouldn't `dt[, .(Frekvens_Pågående = mean(totstatus_bin == 'pågående studier')), keyby = gymnasiegrov]` just work?

Comment: there is `fifelse` which is faster version of `ifelse`

Comment: Right you are. Shall amend with credit (also, thank you for `fifelse`!).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a tidyverse-based option. It also deals with missing values in `gymnasiegrov` correctly, rather than just dropping them:

```r
library(tidyverse)

fulldata %>% 
    group_by_all() %>% 
    count %>% 
    spread(totstatus_bin, n, fill = 0) %>% 
    mutate(ongoing = `pågående studier`/(`pågående studier` + `troligt avbrott eller återbud`))
```

**Output:**

```
# A tibble: 15 x 4
# Groups:   gymnasiegrov [15]
   gymnasiegrov             `pågående studie… `troligt avbrott el… ongoing
   <chr>                                <dbl>                <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 bygg, el, fordon, hantv…                 7                    3   0.7  
 2 ekonomiprogrammet/ ekon…                34                   21   0.618
 3 ekonomiprogrammet/ juri…                 7                    3   0.7  
 4 estetiska programmet                     5                    2   0.714
 5 friskoleprogram                          2                    0   1    
 6 Handels- och administra…                 3                    1   0.75 
 7 Hotell- och Restaurang                   1                    2   0.333
 8 komvux                                   2                    4   0.333
 9 medieprogrammet/mediepr…                 0                    1   0    
10 naturvetenskapliga prog…                 9                    5   0.643
11 samhälls- och ekonomipr…                 1                    0   1    
12 samhällsvetenskapliga p…                11                    5   0.688
13 specialutformat program                  6                    5   0.545
14 teknikprogrammet                         5                    6   0.455
15 NA                                       8                    3   0.727
```

Answer (score 1):

Hej, you can also try simple base R:

```
tab = do.call(rbind,
    tapply(fulldata$totstatus_bin,fulldata$gymnasiegrov,table)
)
# calculate the ratio you wanted
tab = data.frame(tab)
tab$ongoing = tab[,1]/rowSums(tab)
```